How is the gasPrice encoded in Chainlink CCIP `PriceRegistry::getDestinationChainGasPrice`?
In IPriceRegistry.getDestinationChainGasPrice(), the natspec says the gasPrice returned for different chains contains different components.
/// @notice Get an encoded `gasPrice` for a given destination chain ID.
/// The 224-bit result encodes necessary gas price components.
/// On L1 chains like Ethereum or Avax, the only component is the gas price.
/// On Optimistic Rollups, there are two components - the L2 gas price, and L1 base fee for data availability.
/// On future chains, there could be more or differing price components.
/// PriceRegistry does not contain chain-specific logic to parse destination chain price components.
/// @param destChainSelector The destination chain to get the price for.
/// @return gasPrice The encoded gasPrice for the given destination chain ID.
  function getDestinationChainGasPrice(
    uint64 destChainSelector
  ) external view returns (Internal.TimestampedPackedUint224 memory);

In PriceRegistry, the natspec for s_usdPerUnitGasByDestChainSelector says:
/// Logic to parse the price components is chain-specific, and should live in OnRamp.

Where can I find this logic to parse the price components? I looked at EVM2EVMOnRamp, but couldn't find anything.
How is the encoding done differently for each chain?
If the returned value for Ethereum or Avalanche is just the gasPrice, what needs to be done differently to get that same value from a chain where the returned value is made up of multiple components?
Thanks!

Look at the packedGasPrice usage here in OnRamp's getFee method:
It's a 224b field, where:

first (leftmost) half is the L1 data availability gas price (i.e. set only for rollups, where this would be the price of the L1 calldata), and
last (rightmost) half is execution gas price (i.e. what you usually get from web3.eth.gasPrice)


I think, it’s calculated off-chain in the oracle. You can refer to PriceRegistryDestChainConfig struct defined in the price_registry.go file.
Unfortunately, I’m not proficient in Golang, so unable to break it down further.
